# How to spy on nested methods, jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, jasmine, google-cloud-firestore

I need to test a function and the only test case I need help with is to *check if the `dataCollection.add()` method has been called*. I presume a spy is needed here, but any recommendations will be much appreciated.

Here is the **function I need to test** containing the `dataCollection.add()` method:

```
...
constructor(private _firebase: AngularFirestore, private _read: ReadService) {}

createRootCollectionDocument$(collection: string, data: any): Observable<firebase.firestore.DocumentReference> {
   const testt = this._firebase.collection(collection);
   const dataCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this._firebase.collection(collection);
    return Observable.from(
       dataCollection.add({ ...data }).catch((err: firebase.firestore.FirestoreError) => {
          throw err.message;
        })
     );
 }
```

Here is my **test case** as yet:

```
...
beforeEach(() => {
   service = TestBed.get(CrudService);
}

it('uses the firebase collection.add method', () => {
      return service.createRootCollectionDocument$(collectionStub, dataStub).toPromise().then((result) => {
         ...
      })
 });           
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub out `this._firebase.collection` to return a mock object and then see that its `add` function was called.

```
it('uses the firebase collection.add method', () => {

      let mockAdder = jasmine.createSpyObj("adder", ["add"]);
      jasmine.spyOn(service["_firebase"], "collection").andReturn(mockAdder);

      return service.createRootCollectionDocument$(collectionStub, dataStub).toPromise().then((result) => {

          expect(mockAdder.add).toHaveBeenCalled();

      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Motti. I have a problem though.. How will this approach work if I need a value returned from the spy which will be set on 'dataCollection'? How is it then possible to know if the 'add' method was called? Thanks again.

Comment: @D15, you can capture the original function before spying on it, then use `and.callFake` with a function that internally calls the original function and saves some state that it was called (for the `assert`).